# Installing Rational Application Developer for websphere asked for disks

Tags: websphere-portal

I downloaded RAD 8 for websphere from Developer works website.

Amidst  its installation, it prompted for disk 1,2&3. But i could find 'em nowhere in the RAD_SETUP folder.

Where to get those disks?

Answer (score 2):

There's more ZIPs you need to get from Developer Works that are the installation disks.

Comment: nick is right.... also look for repository.config it should pickup everything after setup